# Background color does not work when trying to create my data before using scatter chart with chart.js

Tags: chart.js, scatter

I a creating my dataset as follow:

```
/* Create and add data from excel file to our datasets */
      var marksData = {
        labels: marqueurs,
        datasets: []
      };

      var colors = ['#ef335a','#ec83aa','#9eae3c','#a75a94','#d9acce','#2a345e'];
      var domaines = [' GROUP1','GROUP2','GROUP3','GROUP4','GROUP5'];
      
      for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        marksData.datasets[i] = [];
        marksData.datasets[i].label = domaines[i];
        marksData.datasets[i].data = [{}];
        marksData.datasets[i].backgroundColor = colors[i];
      }
      
      for (i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {
        var indexDomaine = domaines.indexOf(json1[i].Domaine);
        var res = parseInt(json1[i].Resilience * 100);
        var freq = parseInt(json1[i].Frequence * 100);
        var lengthData = marksData.datasets[indexDomaine].data.length;
        marksData.datasets[indexDomaine].data[lengthData] = {};
        marksData.datasets[indexDomaine].data[lengthData].x = res;
        marksData.datasets[indexDomaine].data[lengthData].y = freq;
        marksData.datasets[indexDomaine].pointRadius = 10;
        marksData.datasets[indexDomaine].pointHoverRadius = 15;
        marksData.datasets[indexDomaine].showLine = "false";
        marksData.datasets[indexDomaine].fill = "true";
        
      }
```

I then display the scatter chart as follow:

```
 var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: marksData,
        options: {
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                  xAxes: [
                    {
                      type: 'linear',
                      ticks: {
                        min: 50,
                        max: 100,
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  yAxes: [
                    {
                      type: 'linear',
                      ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                legend: {
                    display:true,
                    position:'bottom',
                },
                title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'My title'
                },
                tooltips: {
                     callbacks: {
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                           var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                           return label;
                        }
                     }
                  }
        }
      });
```

But then my points in the chart and the group labels (Group1, Group2..) are not in color.
Although I checked in the console and have the backgroundColor inside...
How can I resolve this issue?
Thanks for your help
Sophie

Answer (score 0):

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7zxmn9h/) to reproduce what you are trying to do. I can see that the colours are rendering fine after making one small change to your code:
I had to set `marksData.datasets[i] = {}` instead of `marksData.datasets[i] = []`

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
     marksData.datasets[i] = {};
     marksData.datasets[i].label = domaines[i];
     marksData.datasets[i].data = [{}];
     marksData.datasets[i].backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

Edit: The issue was you were setting dataset as an array, while it should've been an object.